# Error due to environment start and end in non-active mode

Tags: beamer, beamerarticle

I am making a beamer presentation with a beamerarticle counterpart. On the article version, I want to display some parts side by side, so I created minipages in `<article>` mode that should not affect the `<presentation>` mode.

However, while the article compiles nicely, the presentation yields an error.

Here I stripped it all to a MWE, with a dummy environment instead of minipage :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{machin}{begdef}{enddef}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Exemples}
      \mode
      <article>
        \begin{machin}
        whatever
      \mode
      <all>
      blabla
      \mode
      <article>
        whatever
        \end{machin}
      \mode
      <all>
    \end{exampleblock}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this leads to `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{frame}` at line 20.

Compiling this with the `machin` environments commented out is fine.

Compiling this, including the `machin` environments, with class `scrartcl` and package `beamerarticle` also works.

I am at a loss because in presentation mode, the lines about the `machin` environment should have been gobbled out and not executed.

Does somebody have a clue ?

In my actual file, the text is more complicated so I would like to avoid duplicating the whole thing for presentation/article.

Comment: I would say it is a variant of the bug you already reported: https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/issues/543

Comment: Ah ! I had not thought that one would come back in disguise to bite me again ! I will add this to the report there and try to remember how I worked around the previous incarnation.